# Why is this function returning undefined but not loggin in console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console.log

```js
function getIcon(id) {
    var icons = {
     'i8' : 'nachos1',
     'i4' : 'eggs',
     'i6': 'glass2',
     'i5': 'drink',
     'i1': 'starter',
     'i2': 'steak',
     'i3': 'ice-cream2',
     'i10': 'carrot',
     'i9': 'bread',
     'i7': 'pizza',
     'i11' : 'salad'
  };
  console.log('getIcon'); /* Wont happen */
  return 'icon-'+icons[id]; 
}

$app = {
  init: function() {
    $el = $('div.el');
    console.log($el.data('id')); /* i5 */
    var icon = getIcon[$el.data('id')];
    console.log(icon); /* undefined */
    $el.text(icon);
  }
}
$(function(){
  $app.init();
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:50px;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
(it should be 'icon-drink')
<div class="el" data-id="i5"></div>
```

I am trying to fetch the icon class based on the id,

But the function that does it allways retrun undefined, and it won't log in console,

Any idea what i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the square brackets for parentheses:

`getIcon[$el.data('id')]` should be `getIcon($el.data('id'))`

Square brackets are for property access; parentheses are for function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The `getIcon` is not an array/object, but you refer it as such:

```
getIcon[$el.data('id')]
```

Change it to

```
getIcon($el.data('id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Swap the Square Brackets to round Brackets

```
getIcon[$el.data('id')]
```

Change To

```
getIcon($el.data('id'))
```